# Move_base/dwa parameters for a large robot with rotation center in the front

Tags: ros, navigation, differential-drive, dwa-local-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit 1: Video Link to Trial 1- [link text](http://youtu.be/c8W49WZOCWA)

Edit 2: Video Link to Trial N - Working but not perfect system: [here](http://youtu.be/LzyMQVSJvzY)

Dear Navigation experts and other respective ROS users,

I have been struggling with an annoying problem for a while which I hope you can help me to solve it.

**Robot properties:**

I have a robot with the following size: **70x60x50(L,W,H)**. (Volksbot RT3 differential drive, modified and bigger). This robot has two maxon 150w engines, and two maxon controllers with 74:1 gears.

The rotation centre of the robot is on the front axis of the robot, and therefore I have the base_link and base_footprint on that point. This point is 12cm behind from the front of the robot.

We use ROS Hydro, Ubuntu 12.04

Sensors:

Laser: in the front

- Front_rotating_xtion -> down sampled to leaf size of 5cm
- Back_fixed_xtion -> down sampled to leaf size of 5cm
- I use multiple obstacle layers so the sensors do not overwrite each other

Note: We started using xtions/kinect since Fuerte, and we always had to make two observation sources for one camera, and set one for marking and the other for clearing. Otherwise it wouldn't work. (Perhaps it changed but we didn't try)

**Problem**

When I give a navigation goal, the global plan is somewhat reasonable. I intentionally increased the inflation radius in the global costmap to avoid having tricky situation.
My problem is that the dwa local planner puts the robot in very a difficult situations, and the robot gets stuck easily while there is a clear solution to the movement problem. Instead of following the path, it likes to stick to obstacles, and get itself stuck. When stuck, it keeps oscillating instead of move in reverse and correct its path.
I do not penalize negative_x movement because the robot can see its behind pretty good.
I read all the documentations for all sections of move_base. I changed a lot of variables to see the effect, but none of them really satisfied me, because the robot gets stuck so easily, and it doesn't get out of it.

Below the text are my move_base parameter files (Hopefully it can be also used as a reference for people who are trying to get hydro style move_Base to work with multiple sensors):

**The things I have tried:**

For DWA robot configuration parameters, I checked the plotted cmd_vel versus the odometry reading. The perfect plot match was with the given parameters below. (I used rqt_plot)

- I fiddled around with all the Forward simulation parameters, and the trajectory scoring parameters.
- I increased/decreased the inflation radius for both local and global costmap, and increase/decreased their resolution.
- I tried changing the reference frame to the centre of the robot instead of centre of rotation.
- I fiddled around with controller_frequency and planner and controller patience.
- I checked whether the TF matches the robot (with xtions veiwing the robot)
- I will prepare a video link and add it here so you can view the problem better.

**Things I would like to know**

I would greatly appreciate any hint or direction to a better results. Meanwhile I have some more directed questions.

1. How does the dwa_local_planner know about the rotation axis length of the robot? Is it from the footprint?
2. My footprint is a simplified almost rectangular bounding box of the robot. Does it make a difference If I make it precise enough to exactly match the footprint of the robot?
3. Is the Cost value example in the dwa_local_planner webpage that is calculated from the goal_distance , path_distance and occdist values a positive (the high the better path) or negative value? On top of the page it talks about a scoring trajectory but below the example is cost, so I am a bit confused.
4. Do you know why the robot fails while there is a clear solution available?

Move_base launch file:

```
<launch>

    <!-- Run the map server -->
    <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/test/ros/maps/2nd_floor.yaml"/>
    
    <!--- Run AMCL -->
    <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
        <param name="base_frame_id" value="base_footprint"/>
        <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
        <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
        <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
        <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.001"/>
        <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.1"/>
        <param name="laser_max_beams" value="100"/>
        <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>
        <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
        <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.2"/>
        <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/>
    </node>

    <!-- Run move_base -->
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" clear_params="true" output="screen">
        <rosparam file="$(find alice_nav)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find alice_nav)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find alice_nav)/config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find alice_nav)/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find alice_nav)/config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <param name="controller_frequency" value="10" />
        <param name="clearing_rotation_allowed" value="false" />
        <param name="planner_patience" value="5" />
        <param name="controller_patience" value="5" />
        <param name="conservative_reset_dist" value="8" />
        <param name="oscillation_distance" value="0.1" />
        <param name="oscillation_timeout" value="10" />

        <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"/>  
    </node>
</launch>
```

Common Costmap params:

```
map_type: costmap

footprint: [ [0.1, -0.28], [0.1, 0.28], [-0.58, 0.25], [-0.58, -0.25] ]
footprint_padding: 0.0
inflation_radius: 0.2

obstacle_layer_xtions:
  back_point_cloud_sensor: {clearing: false, data_type: PointCloud2, expected_update_rate: 0.4, obstacle_range: 1.5, raytrace_range: 2, marking: true, min_obstacle_height: 0.1, sensor_frame: back_xtion_link, topic: back_xtion_voxel_grid/output}
  back_point_cloud_sensor2: {clearing: true, data_type: PointCloud2, expected_update_rate: 0.4, obstacle_range: 1.5, raytrace_range: 2, marking: false, min_obstacle_height: -0.1, sensor_frame: back_xtion_link, topic: back_xtion_voxel_grid/output}
  front_point_cloud_sensor: {clearing: false, data_type: PointCloud2, expected_update_rate: 0.4, obstacle_range: 2.5, raytrace_range: 3, marking: true, min_obstacle_height: 0.1, sensor_frame: front_xtion_link, topic: front_xtion_voxel_grid/output}
  front_point_cloud_sensor2: {clearing: true, data_type: PointCloud2, expected_update_rate: 0.4, obstacle_range: 2.5, raytrace_range: 3, marking: false, min_obstacle_height: -0.1, sensor_frame: front_xtion_link, topic: front_xtion_voxel_grid/output}

obstacle_layer_laser:
  laser_scan_sensor: {clearing: true, data_type: LaserScan, expected_update_rate: 0.1, marking: true, obstacle_range: 4, raytrace_range: 6, sensor_frame: laser, topic: scan}
```

Local Costmap:

```
  local_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  
  height: 5
  width: 5 
  origin_x: -4.0
  origin_y: -4.0
  rolling_window: true
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  resolution: 0.025
  static_map: false
  transform_tolerance: 0.3
  update_frequency: 5.0

  plugins:
  - {name: obstacle_layer_xtions, type: 'costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer'}
  - {name: obstacle_layer_laser, type: 'costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer'}
  - {name: inflation_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::InflationLayer'}
  
  inflation_layer: {cost_scaling_factor: 10.0, enabled: true, inflation_radius: 0.2}
  
  obstacle_layer_xtions:
    observation_sources: front_point_cloud_sensor front_point_cloud_sensor2 back_point_cloud_sensor back_point_cloud_sensor2
    enabled: true
    track_unknown_space: false
  obstacle_layer_laser:
    observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
    track_unknown_space: true
    enabled: true
  obstacle_layer_footprint: {enabled: true}
```

Global Costmap:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  #Height and width of costmap
  height: 15
  width: 15
  origin_x: -7
  origin_y: -7
  
  publish_frequency: 0.5
  resolution: 0.05
  
  transform_tolerance: 0.5
  update_frequency: 1.0

  plugins:
  - {name: static_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::StaticLayer'}
  - {name: obstacle_layer_laser, type: 'costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer'}
  - {name: obstacle_layer_xtions, type: 'costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer'}
  - {name: inflation_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::InflationLayer'}
  
  static_layer: {enabled: true}
  static_map: true
  
  inflation_layer: {cost_scaling_factor: 10.0, enabled: true, inflation_radius: 0.2}
  obstacle_layer_xtions:
    observation_sources: front_point_cloud_sensor front_point_cloud_sensor2 back_point_cloud_sensor back_point_cloud_sensor2
    track_unknown_space: true
    enabled: true

  obstacle_layer_laser:
    observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
    track_unknown_space: true
    enabled: true
    
  obstacle_layer_footprint: {enabled: true}
```

dwa_local_planner params:

```
DWAPlannerROS:
#Robot Config Params
  acc_lim_theta: 0.35
  acc_lim_x: 0.3
  acc_lim_y: 0.0
  acc_limit_trans: 0.35
  max_vel_x: 0.25
  min_vel_x: -0.1 
  max_vel_y: 0.0
  min_vel_y: 0.0
  max_trans_vel: 0.25
  min_trans_vel: 0.01
  max_rot_vel: 0.25
  min_rot_vel: 0.01
#Forward Simulation Parameters
  sim_time: 10
  sim_granularity: 0.025
  vx_samples: 30
  vy_samples: 0
  vtheta_samples: 40
  penalize_negative_x: false
#Trajectory Scoring Parameters
  goal_distance_bias: 32.0
  path_distance_bias: 24
  occdist_scale: 0.01
  stop_time_buffer: 0.2
  forward_point_distance: 0.325
  scaling_speed: 0.1
  max_scaling_factor: 0.2
#Goal Tolerance Parameters
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.17
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: true
  rot_stopped_vel: 0.001
  trans_stopped_vel: 0.001
#Oscillation Prevention Param
  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
#Global Plan PArameters
  prune_plan: true
```

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201535/move_base/dwa-parameters-for-a-large-robot-with-rotation-center-in-the-front/) by [Amir Shantia](https://answers.ros.org/users/659/amir-shantia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2015-01-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-24**:
Can you specify a little more what you mean by "stick to obstacles"? Uploading diagrams would be helpful. (If you can't upload pictures, email me the pictures and I'll edit the question for you).

**Comment by [Amir Shantia](https://answers.ros.org/users/659/amir-shantia/) on 2015-01-25**:
Thank you for responding David. I will take some detailed pictures and videos and will email them tomorrow the latest.

**Comment by [Amir Shantia](https://answers.ros.org/users/659/amir-shantia/) on 2015-01-26**:
I updated the link, and sent some pictures for you to add to the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on [@DavidLu's](http://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) answers I started the following trials:

1. I corrected to the footprint to match the robot as much as possible. It didn't improved very much.
2. I also found out that my robot was not rotating/moving properly, and I fixed it as well. It improved the localization and movement, but the problem was still there.
3. I did fiddle around with inflation radius, it improved the movement. However, the robot could still get stuck frequently, or as you saw in the first video link, it was moving slow.
4. Then I thought well, I am going to read the source code, which helped a lot. and thanks for good coding + comments.
   In [dwa_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner) page, the **forward_point_distance** is defined as an additional scoring point in front of the robot. I frankly didn't understand what it meant. However, in the source code, I found out that this value is being used as a cost value for **robot alignment to the path**. By setting it to zero, the trajectory will not be penalized if the robot is not aligned on the path. This is a **very important factor for differential drive robots whose centre of rotation is not the in the middle of the robot**. Apparently, a lot of valid trajectories were being dropped because of this. As soon as I set this to zero, the robot was able to perform much better. However, improvements could be done so I continued.
5. I found a very interesting debugging feature in the planner which helps in visualizing the simulated trajectory points.  There is a **publish_traj_pc** private node handler parameter value which is false by default. I didn't know how to set it to true from the config files, so I enabled it in the source and recompiled. The only downside was that the trajectory centres was not on the robot (perhaps their base frame was base_footprint or base_link while I was using map as the reference frame). However, if you select odom as the reference frame in the local costmap parameters, the trajectories will be on the robot.
6. Using the new visualization parameter, I played around with sim_time, trajectory scoring parameters, vx_samples, and vtheta_samples (note that vy_sample should be 0 or 1 cause the robot does not move in Y vector space). When the number of samples are high, there is higher chance to find solutions if the robot is in a tricky situation. However, increasing the samples requires extensive calculations and after a point move_base will thell you that desired control frequency cannot be achieved. By increasing sim_period the simulation takes longer, and may help in better solutions, but the downside is not achieving the desired control frequency.

I uploaded another video on youtube with the latest knowledge: [Trial N, success](http://youtu.be/LzyMQVSJvzY)

After a lot of trials, I can conclude that one set of parameters is not enough for a reliable navigation. I would recommend having a couple of settings for different environmental situations. And change the parameters using dynamic reconfigure when the robot gets stuck or fails to reach the goal.

---

Originally posted by [Amir Shantia](https://answers.ros.org/users/659/amir-shantia/) with karma: 86 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-27**:
Glad to hear it. Can we close this question?

**Comment by [Amir Shantia](https://answers.ros.org/users/659/amir-shantia/) on 2015-01-28**:
Yes, of course. I was waiting for enough karma to be able to select the answer. Thanks again for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How does the dwa_local_planner know about the rotation axis length of the robot? Is it from the footprint?

DWA does not explicitly model the rotation axis length. It assumes the rotation happens relative to /base_footprint and uses the footprint to figure out how much space the robot takes up.

> My footprint is a simplified almost rectangular bounding box of the robot. Does it make a difference If I make it precise enough to exactly match the footprint of the robot?

It's not likely that the precision will make a difference unless the footprint is a bad approximation.

> Is the Cost value example in the dwa_local_planner webpage that is calculated from the goal_distance , path_distance and occdist values a positive (the high the better path) or negative value? On top of the page it talks about a scoring trajectory but below the example is cost, so I am a bit confused.

Yes, the language is not clear. It is calculated in terms of costs, not positive scores. It minimizes the sum of the costs.

> Do you know why the robot fails while there is a clear solution available?

One bit is that your inflation radius is too small. It should be at least half the width of your robot (.28)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3